# Autocomplete and IE7 - slowness, sluggishness as overall pagesize grows?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, plugins

I have the autocomplete plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/, version 1.1 and 1.0.2) on a project to add pieces of "equipment" to a "project". On a fresh project the plugin works great; the data returned from the database comes back FAST, you can scroll the list fast, and can select an item and move on to the next one.

Once I have a project established with equipment on it, and I go to add equipment, the performance is pretty bad. It takes 4-5 seconds to get the list of data back from the server, scrolling the list is painful, and the cursor takes several seconds to settle on an item. Repainting the page after the list goes away is slow.

This is occurring in IE7, latest version. FF3 and Chrome are fine, very snappy.

The pagesize is about 40K overall.

I'm thinking this is an issue with the IE7 Javascript engine, or an edge case with this plugin and IE7; it works quickly enough in FF3+.

I would appreciate any ideas, solutions, known issues, or thoughts on how to more specifically pin this down.

I'd love to post sample code, but this is a corporate app, and I'm not how useful it would be given that the server side piece cannot be shown; ie: you can't pull it down and test it like a self contained piece of code..

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Comment: Did you try playing with the `cacheLength` and `max` options of the plugin. If your backend repsonses are large then caching 10 (default) of them could maybe lead to the slow down

Comment: Yeah, I have a database table of 25k-35k rows that I'm pulling from. So, the answer is YES, the count of the data coming back could be substantial. I have not tried those two options - will do. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I've played with these two options with little success. Basically (IE7) I enter 3-4 characters into the input; it takes 5+ seconds to get results back; I scroll or mouse up and down the results and the CPU pegs at 99%. IE8 in compat mode is ~50% cpu. Still looking for an answer or a direction to search...

Comment: I finally got this fixed late last week. Turns out I was using the livequery (jQuery) plugin, and the js engine in IE7 couldn't keep up with the cpu cycles it was taking to manage its events. I ended up refactoring several of the items on the page that had been using livequery, and manually wired/rewired those events, and now the page zings in IE7. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments above. The basic moral is that IE7's rendering engine is ancient, and just can't keep up with Chrome, Safari, etc. Don't use livequery all over the place and expect to get good performance in IE7.